# Can I overwrite User.objects.delete in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I used to delete a user when the user is left, but a lot of models relates User which I need to set related foreign key to empty or delete them since then.

But some models would be pointless since the related User is deleted, such as `Order`. Thus I need to set `User.is_active` or something similar to invalid instead of delete the data.

I think it would be best If I can override `User.objects.delete`, so I don't need to modify a lot of business functions relates to it.

Comment: just create a flag which denotes whether an user is active or not.

Comment: Hi what exactly is the question? You seem to have answered it yourself as you can override the delete method

Comment: @BenJ I mean ``User.objects.delete`` is used in somewhere of my code, and I want to override it to set ``is_active`` to false instead, so that won't break my code. User is not the only model that need to set flag instead of delete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `django.contrib.auth.User` already has an [`is_active`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active) parameter, so you can just set that.

In fact, from the docs linked above:

> We recommend that you set this flag to False instead of deleting accounts; that way, if your applications have any foreign keys to users, the foreign keys won’t break.

Yes, technically you can override `delete` by setting a new Manager, but its the wrong approach.

Comment: What's a Manager mean? I'd like to have a look it first.

Comment: @kxxoling - [Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#managers)